# How to Choose When to Return Collection View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I am trying to create a collection view list and it uses CoreData. It displays tasks, the tasks are the CoreData entity and it has attributes such as name etc.

What I want it to do is that if the attribute (in this case 'pid') equals a certain value, then return the collection view cell like normal however if not then don't return cell. This is how my cellForItemAt looks like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "connectCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    if idVar == task.pid {

        cell.labelTe?.text = task.name

    } else {
        print("blank cell?")
    }

    if cell.labelTe.text == "" {
        print("cell is nil")
        cell.isHidden = true
    }

    self.myCollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 25

    //Swipe gesture register
    let cSelector = #selector(reset(sender:))
    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: cSelector )
    leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

    return cell
}
```

The problem with this solution is that although the cell is hidden if idVar != task.pid, it still affects the ordering and causes strange effects such as a lot of blank space above a collection view cell where the hidden cells are meant to be.

This is the function to get data:

```
func getData() {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
    tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())


    }

    catch {
     print("Get Data failed")
    }

    // Fetches data.

}
```

This is the Task array being declared:

```
var tasks : [Task] = []
```

and this is my viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myCollView.delegate = self
    self.myCollView.dataSource = self

    print("In next view")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    getData()
    myCollView.reloadData()
}
```

I tried using the if statement over everything in the function with the exception of 'let task = tasks[indexPath.row]', however I got an error as the return would need to be outside the if statement which would delete the whole purpose of it. How can selectively display cells if idVar == task.pid but if not then it doesn't display at all?

Comment: I don't really understand what your app is attempting to do but I would try to never even reach `cellForItamAtIndexPath:` by filtering my data source. That way you are only ever asked for cells you want to display.

Comment: @RoboticCat the idea of the app is that you have one view controller that contains a collection view and in there are projects (that contain tasks) if you click on one of them, you go to the next view controller (the one mentioned in the question) and here you have tasks and can create tasks but it saves these tasks under the project you are in and won't display in the others. What I am trying to achieve is to not display any cells that don't have idVar == pid however the closest i've gotten is to hide them but the places those cells would have taken is now blank. Thanks for asking

Comment: In that case, you need to do what I suggested and filter your data source so that it only contains (or only returns) those tasks for the specific project. `collection​View(_:​cell​For​Item​At:​):` is too late to do this so it needs to be done in the `collection​View(_:​number​Of​Items​In​Section:​)` (or even earlier so that the array only contains the correct items).

Comment: @RoboticCat I understand what you mean by filtering it before cellForItemAt however I am not sure how to practically do that. I import the CoreData using 'var tasks : [Task] = []' and I am not sure how to filter out. I think that doing something with numberOfItemsInSection could fix the problem however I am not sure of any practical way. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Please share the code where you fetch your object (create the Task array).  As @RoboticCat has pointed out, that is the code that needs to be changed.

Comment: @JonRose I just added in my getData function and how the Task variable was created including the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear to the question, thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fetch request `Task.fetchRequest()` is fetching all tasks because the predicate property is not set.  Instead attach a predicate to the fetch so you only get the objects that you want.

```
let fetchRequest = Task.fetchRequest();
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "pid = %@", idVar);
tasks = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

You probably also want to set the sort order using the sortDescriptors property.

Comment: I put it in the 'do {}' however I get the error saying "Cannot invoke 'fetch' with an argument list of type '(NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)' " Do you know why it is giving an error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry to bother, I typed in the new code and got 2 errors, "Value of type 'Task' has no member 'predicate'" and "Cannot convert value of type 'Task' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>'". Maybe I need to initialize the predicate? Sorry to bother, but do you know how to fix it?

Comment: updated again.  sorry, i'm in the middle of 20 things.